Show $1+\cos(\theta)+\cos(2\theta)+\cos(3\theta)+...cos(n\theta) = \frac{1-\cos(\theta)+\cos(n\theta)-\cos(n+1\theta)}{2-2\cos(\theta)}$
Apologies if my formatting is poor, a bit new to LaTex.
I have looked at similar questions in this vein, but I am having trouble getting from one step to another.
I have gotten this far :
$$\begin{align}
1+\cos(\theta)+\cos(2\theta)+\cos(3\theta)+\dots+\cos(n\theta) &=\Re\left(\frac{1-e^{(n+1)i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right) \\[6pt]
&=\frac{1-\cos((n+1)\theta)-i\sin((n+1)\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)} \\[6pt]
 \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
I then multiply the top and bottom by $(1-\cos(\theta)) + i\sin(\theta)$ and get (only concerned with the real part of the equation):

$$\frac{1-\cos(\theta)-\cos(n+1)\theta+(\cos(\theta)\cos(n+1)\theta)+(\sin(\theta)\sin(n+1)\theta)}{2-2\cos(\theta)} \tag{3}$$

So the denominator is OK, and the numerator is very close, but unless I made some error in my multiplication I cannot find my way to getting the $\cos(n\theta)$ into the numerator as desired.
Any insight would be mighty helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Right after posting, the insight (read: face palm) came:
$\cos(n+1)\theta\cos\theta + sin(n+1)\theta\sin\theta = \cos((n+1)\theta-\theta) = \cos n\theta$
